# Why some of Numpy is written in C++?

Tags: numpy

In https://github.com/numpy/numpy it is found that 2.8% of numpy code is C++. Is it just for interfacing with users' C++ codes (like 0.1% of code which is written in fortran) or is some functionality of numpy built on this code?

And if some functionality of numpy is built on this C++ code, why didn't they use C for those purposes?

Comment: You can clone the repo and search for all files named `*.{cc,cpp,cxx}` which points one to https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/tools/swig, whose README explains its purpose pretty clearly

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if "why" questions are ontopic on this site, they're usually opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on [C++ 2.8%](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/search?l=c%2B%2B), you'll get a list of files that GitHub has labeled as C++.   If you then inspect those files, you'll see that many of them are not, in fact, C++.  They are mostly C header files, or files with the `.inc` extension that are actually C files.  So it looks like GitHub has categorized many of these files incorrectly, and the only actual C++ files are SWIG test files.

Comment: I got the '.inc' part, but are you saying that '.h' files are only found in C, and not C++? (Pardon my complete infamiliarity to C++)

Comment: No.  Both C and C++ use the extension `.h` for header files.  *In this case*, the `.h` files are C files.